# FSharp.Core not optimized?

Tags: f#, cil

I've recently inspected the performance of a F# app and while digging through the CIL I've found out that FSharp.Core (for .NET v4.0) contains several nop instructions, many unused variables and variables which are only written/read once via sequences of stloc/ldloc instructions.
I've investigated the possible causes and I've noticed that even in release mode F# assemblies include the --debug:pdbonly directive and there's no way to disable this and switch to --debug- from the project settings UI.
I'm wondering if there was a specific choice for the compilation settings of FSharp.Core and if so what was that. Otherwise is it legitimate to expect a fully optimized version of the runtime?

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612543/nop-in-release-build-of-f-code

Comment: `--debug:pdbonly` is normal for release code, this only includes limited debug info and allows stacks to be decoded. All of Windows (including .NET) is built like that: this is how MS can provide symbols on their Symbol servers.

Comment: @Richard: thanks. I suspected debug-related reasons, however I'm left wondering whether there'd be performance benefits with a more optimized version...In performance-critical, compute-bound apps one would hope to be able to sacrifice debugging ability to squeeze every cpu cycle...

Comment: @emaster70: PDB only debug information has no performance implication, I make no comment on the core of your question.

Comment: Did your profiling find specific issues with the F# core library?  I'd expect the JIT compiler to ignore any nops, so I wouldn't expect this to introduce any real-world performance issues.

Comment: Actually I stumbled upon the nops in FSharp.Core when I decided to see how widespread was their presence in the core library; my profiling only revealed excessive use of functions from the Seq module and some boxing/unboxing related to that (talking about my code, not the core). When I went down to the CIL code to investigate the boxing/unboxing I started to find the nops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the comments on the question have already answered about 90% of this; to reiterate them:

- nearly every release binary in the universe is compiled with --debug:pdbonly
- even if the IL code is sub-optimal, this may not have any real-world impact due to the JIT optimizing it away

There are, of course, all kinds of ways the F# compiler could be potentially emitting better code (this is probably true of every compiler); if you profile your app and notice something bad (e.g. a big discrepancy versus comparable code from C#) then you can let the F# team know by mailing fsbugs.  But measure first.

Answer (score 1):

> Otherwise is it legitimate to expect a fully optimized version of the runtime?

The changes you suggest cannot reasonably be regarded as optimizations. Both are harmless and will be compiled away by the VM. ISTR, mutation is used to replace stacking because the stack-based VM can stack overflow. So that is F# correctly working around a bug in the CLR.